# No Error/Exception Message in Logcat - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Problem: Why is there no exception message when app crashes?

below is the code that causes the error. For reference: Usecase is only for communication with repository. While repository is only for call from the Api. No additional code is added in both usecase and repository.

```
private fun fetchMovies(
        language: String? = null, page: Int? = null, region: String? = null, timeWindow: String
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _homeUiState.update {
                it.copy(isLoading = true)
            }
            val nowPlaying = async { nowPlayingUseCase(language, page, region) }
            val popularMovies = async { popularMoviesUseCase(language, page, region) }
            val trendingMovies = async { trendingMoviesUseCase(timeWindow) }
            try {
                val nowPlayingResponse = nowPlaying.await()
                val popularMoviesResponse = popularMovies.await()
                val trendingMoviesResponse = trendingMovies.await()
                _homeUiState.update {
                    it.copy(
                        nowPlaying = apiResponseHandler(nowPlayingResponse),
                        popularMovies = apiResponseHandler(popularMoviesResponse),
                        trendingMovies = apiResponseHandler(trendingMoviesResponse)
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _homeUiState.update {
                    it.copy(userMessage = e.localizedMessage ?: "Unexpected error occurs")
                }
            } finally {
                _homeUiState.update {
                    it.copy(isLoading = false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the cause of the crash is due to IOException (connection is set to airplane mode), and can be handled by using a supervisor scope. For some reason Android Studio's Logcat doesn't show any error messages. The only error I got is "FATAL EXCEPTION: main". Any idea why there is no error/exception details in the Logcat?

below is the screenshot of the Logcat (API Key is hidden)

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (17889) for package com.example.moviesapp ----------------------------
2022-10-11 11:16:22.013 17889-17914 HostConnection          com.example.moviesapp                D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-10-11 11:16:22.913 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?page=1&api_key=API_KEY
2022-10-11 11:16:22.913 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> END GET
2022-10-11 11:16:22.929 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.themoviedb.org": No address associated with hostname
2022-10-11 11:16:22.945 17889-17889 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.moviesapp                D  Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10170; state: ENABLED
2022-10-11 11:16:23.051 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?page=1&api_key=API_KEY
2022-10-11 11:16:23.051 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> END GET
2022-10-11 11:16:23.052 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.themoviedb.org": No address associated with hostname
2022-10-11 11:16:23.116 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?api_key=API_KEY
2022-10-11 11:16:23.116 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  --> END GET
2022-10-11 11:16:23.117 17889-17935 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.moviesapp                I  <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.themoviedb.org": No address associated with hostname
2022-10-11 11:16:23.137 17889-17889 AndroidRuntime          com.example.moviesapp                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.moviesapp, PID: 17889
2022-10-11 11:16:23.157 17889-17889 Process                 com.example.moviesapp                I  Sending signal. PID: 17889 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (17889) for package com.example.moviesapp ----------------------------
```